# Difficulty in Launching Applications (simultaneously) installed through an Application

Tags: android

I am new to android..Actually iam trying to increase the RAM Memory of android phone through my app..For that I had created an activity from which i could Launch the other applications present in our phone.This approach is sucessfully reducing RAM memory.But i am facing a difficulty,as i couldnot see the PARENT activity after the launch of the Application. I need to push the other activities (that are launched) to be run in the background as soon as it has been launch and always i need the Parent activity to be visible..

```
package com.android;

import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.MemoryInfo;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
/**
 * GraphViewDemo creates some dummy data to demonstrate the GraphView component.
 * @author Arno den Hond
 **/
public class VsActivity extends Activity {
  /**
     * Variable Array for GraphView
     * verlabel : Background Height Values
     * horlabel : Background Width Values
     * values : Max Values of Foreground Active Graph
     */
    private float[] values = new float[60]; 
    long availableMegs;
    private String[] verlabels = new String[]     { "500","450","400","350","300","250","200","150","100","50","0"};
    private String[] horlabels = new String[] {"0","10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60"};
    private GraphView graphView;
    private LinearLayout graph;
    private boolean runnable = false;
    public static int datasend,test=0;
    int cnt=0;
    Activity activity = this.activity;
    static int count=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        graph = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.graph);
        graphView = new GraphView(this, values, "TEST GRAPH", horlabels, verlabels,    GraphView.LINE);
        graph.addView(graphView);
        runnable = true;
        startDraw.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        runnable = false;
    }

    public void setGraph(){
        int i,j;
        count=count+10;
        try{
                j=values.length-1;
        for(i=0; i<values.length-1; i++){
            values[i] = values[i+1];
        }
        MemoryInfo mi = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
        datasend= (int)((mi.availMem / 1048576));
 values[values.length-1] = (float) datasend;        
graph.removeView(graphView);
        graph.addView(graphView);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // e.printstacktrace();
        }
    } 

private void  launchComponent(String packageName, String name){
    System.out.println("launch application "+datasend);
    Intent launch_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    launch_intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    launch_intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, name));
    launch_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    if(datasend > 24){
        System.out.println("launch application inside if "+packageName+"   "+name);
    this.startActivity(launch_intent);
    }
}

public void startApplication(){
    String application_name = "";
    test=1;
    //ContextWrapper activity = this.activity;
    try{
        System.out.println("Start application ");
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        List<android.content.pm.PackageInfo> packageList;
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        packageList = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveinfo_list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

        for(ResolveInfo info:resolveinfo_list){
            application_name = info.activityInfo.packageName;
            System.out.println(info.activityInfo.packageName+"    "+info.activityInfo.name);
            //if(info.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(application_name)){
                launchComponent(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
              //  break;
           // }
        }
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "There was a problem loading the application: "+application_name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg){
        switch(msg.what){

        case 0x01:
           setGraph();
          // if(test == 0){
          startApplication();//}
           break;
        }
    }
};

public Thread startDraw = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(runnable){
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0x01);
            try{
                MemoryInfo mi = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
                ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
                long ava = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
                //count=(int)ava;
                //System.out.println("SUDARHAN RAMAN    "+ava+"   "+count);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e){
                // e.printstacktrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
}
```

Here the GraphView is a View which will draw a Graph using Canvas.drawline(...)
In the above code **startapplication()** will launch the child (application installed in our phone) activities..

Plz help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            PackageManager manager = mContext.getPackageManager();
            i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(_AppPkgName);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(i);
```

Comment: This will launch all the application present in our phone? how to know whether the app is launched or not? ...If my question is silly forgive me bcoz iam new to android..

Comment: what you want to do exactly. Do you want to open application installed in your phone from your own activity or anything else?

Comment: i got a scenario like this to do..basically i need to do stress test like stuff,,for that we have 2 scenarios/environment 1) based on lowering the battery level and test , 2)Increase the Ram Memory and Internal Memory usage and test...Now currently we need 2 set up an environment like above points and den do stress test an app...For increse the Ram usage i thought to launch multiple application from one application..

Comment: yes sir i need to open application installed from my own activity

Comment: Than you can open it using the above code i provided...

Comment: you just need to insert package name of the application which you want to open

Comment: Thank u sir i could open the applications installed in my phone simultaneously.. But i got one difficulty,i need to make that apps to run in background..

Comment: one thing you can do is after launching these application you can again launch your application and you can store some values in sharedpref to know where to go....that may not be good approach, but you can try this..i am also trying for other ways!

Comment: Sir I tried like that but it didnt work..I dont know how to proceed..